# Custom impromptuobject for json.net deserialization

Tags: json.net, impromptu-interface

I was playing around with impromptu interface over a jobject and ran into the following issue

https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/issues/detail?id=17

The issue is marked as 'Won't fix' and in the comments the author says that it could be fixed by implementing a custom impromptuobject.

Anyone have a sample of such an implementation? Or know another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that `JArray` has GetEnumerator() defined as interface-only, which makes the method no longer duck callable by the DLR. So below I've overriden the `trygetmember` to check if the result is a `JArray`'s and convert it to a `JEnumerable` that implements GetEnumerator() in a dlr invokable way.

```
 public class NonRecursiveJArrayConversionDictionary : ImpromptuDictionary{

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if(base.TryGetMember(binder, out result)){
          if(result is JArray){
             result = ((JArray)result).AsJEnumerable();
          }
          return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
 }
```

However, this will only work for json structures that don't have arrays more then one property deep. You'll either have modify the above to recursively check anytime anything is returned maybe with a proxy,  or modify the dictionary indexer's `set` to check and convert when deserialized instead.

---

**Update:** Json.net verion >= 5.0.4.16101 and ImpromptuInterface >= 6.1.4 will work out of the box.

```
void Main()
{
    ICustomer customer = Impromptu.ActLike(JObject.Parse(@"
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name:'Test',
            Location:'Somewhere',
            Employees: [
                { Id:1, EmployerId:39421, Name:'Joe' },
                { Id:2, EmployerId:39421, Name:'Jane' },
            ]
        }
    "));

    foreach(var employee in customer.Employees){
        employee.Id.Dump();
        employee.Name.Dump();
    }
}


public interface ICustomer
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Location { get; set; }
    IList<IEmployee> Employees { get; } 
}

public interface IEmployee
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int EmployerId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, at least now I know why it is this way!

Comment: @YvesGoeleven This percolated a bit more in the back of my head, I think there might be value, beyond just impromptu interface, to fixing this in json.net, I'll let you know if I submit a patch to json.net for this.

Comment: @YvesGoeleven did pull request, we shall see. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/79